# android calling php but response isn't readable

Tags: android, httpresponse, bufferedreader

I'm trying to query from a php script as the following:

```
http://xxxx.com/ccvo/mel-asset-data/query.php?lon=144.963620993985&lat=-37.8140023779914&within=20&category=Litter Bin
```

The results from the webpage query will be in plain text like the following:

```
4|Litter Bin,-37.8141472000103,144.963691391683,17.2492037024|Litter Bin,
37.8141472763581,144.963685395193,17.0753971521|Litter Bin,
37.8139653160326,144.963765797949,13.3704129156|Litter Bin,
37.8139469233985,144.963755935562,13.3613106302
```

I need to pass values to the four parametsers. My code so far is getting error 200 which means it has access to the web. Also, the query is formated well, and when do Log.d I get the following:

```
query[lon=144.963620993985, lat=-37.8140023779914, within=4, keyword=Litter Bin]
```

Then I need to parse the results as the following: 
number of results, (lon and lat), within, keyword

my could is:

```
    public class myMapService extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        private keyword activity;
        private int id = -1;
        private String rst = " " ; 


        public myMapService(keyword activity, ProgressDialog progressDialog)
        {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            progressDialog.show();
        }


        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            String result = "";
            int responseCode = 0;
            try 
            {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxxx.com/ccvo/mel-asset-data/query.php");

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lon", "144.963620993985"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", "-37.8140023779914"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("within", "20"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("keyword", "Litter Bin"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,HTTP.UTF_8));

            Log.v("URL", " with query" + nameValuePairs);

            int executeCount = 0;
            HttpResponse response;
            do
            {
                progressDialog.setMessage("Passing paratmeters.. ("+(executeCount+1)+"/5)");
                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                executeCount++;
                response = client.execute(httppost);
                responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();                        
                // If you want to see the response code, you can Log it
                // out here by calling:
                // Log.d("256 Design", "statusCode: " + responseCode)
                //InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();


               // Log.d("256 Design", " Response print" + response);


            } while (executeCount < 5 && responseCode == 408);


            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            //Log.d("Results", " Inside whileloops " + rd);

            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
            {
                result = line.trim();
                sb.append(line);

                rst = result.toString();



            }


            Log.v("Results", "rst " + sb);
            id = Integer.parseInt(result);

        }



        catch (Exception e) {
            responseCode = 408;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d("Results", "from web: " + rst);


        return responseCode;

    }



@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer headerCode)
{
    progressDialog.dismiss();

}
}
```

---

when I do Log.d to the response or the BufferedReader , I get something like this :

```
-java.io.BufferedReader@40fc93c8
-printorg.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@40f746b8
```

I need help please to get the results and parse them.

Thank you,
A.

Answer (score 0):

Improved answer

```
public void postData() {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxxx.com/ccvo/mel-asset-data/query.php");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lon", "144.963620993985"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lon", "144.963620993985"));

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
} 





BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()),
                8 * 1024);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

                    Log.d("response", "Response data:\n" + sb + "\n");
```

This will add the response to the StringBuilder and that you can print, this should contain the information you want to display. Because BufferReader is an object that is why it logs the object id.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried your code. rd returns "0". Usually 0 means no results from the query. I guess the problem with my query rather than my BufferReader.

Comment: When I Log.d 'nameValuePairs' I get 'query[lon=144.963620993985, lat=-37.8140023779914, within=4, keyword=Litter Bin]'. Does this match the URL parameters ('http://xxxx.com/ccvo/mel-asset-data/query.php?lon=144.963620993985&lat=-37.8140023779914&within=20&category=Litter Bin') ?

Comment: What do you expect to return from the php?

Comment: Did you tried to hard code the parameters? 


such as:
       HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxxx.com/ccvo/mel-asset-data/query.php?lon=144.963620993985&lat=-37.8140023779914&within=20&category=Litter Bin");

What is then the result of rd still 0?

Comment: if you in my original post, you will see the full query (parameters) within the URL. If the values to the parameters  are valid, it will return some results I mentioned a sample earlier otherwise it will return 0.

Comment: Check the improved answer, does that makes any sense for you?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually I saw this sample code before and I  used it. But my problem is to get may values passing the parameters as if URL is "query.php?lon=144.963620993985&lat=-37.8140023779914&within=20&category=Litter Bin"
I think that I'm getting results 0 because I couldn't match with this query form.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was doing POST method other than GET ;/

any way I solved the problem with this issue. This is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;



import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;


import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class myMapService extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private keyword activity;
    private int id = -1;
    private String rst = " " ; 

    protected String getASCIIContentFromEntity(HttpEntity entity) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
        InputStream in = entity.getContent();
        StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
        int n = 1;
        while (n>0) {
        byte[] b = new byte[4096];
        n =  in.read(b);
        if (n>0) out.append(new String(b, 0, n));
        }
        return out.toString();
        }


    public myMapService(keyword activity, ProgressDialog progressDialog)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        progressDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... arg0) {


        String result = "";
        int responseCode = 0;

        int executeCount = 0;
        HttpResponse response;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        try 
        {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("http://XXXXXX/ccvo/mel-asset-data/query.php?lon="+ arg0[0].toString() + "&lat="+ arg0[1].toString() +"&within=" + arg0[2].toString()  + "&category="+ arg0[3].toString().replace(" ", "%20"));

                do
                {
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Passing paratmeters.. ("+(executeCount+1)+"/5)");
                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    executeCount++;
                    response = client.execute(httppost);
                    responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();                        

                } while (executeCount < 5 && responseCode == 408);

                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    result = line.trim();
                    sb.append(line);
                    rst = result.toString();

                }
        }catch (Exception e2) {
            responseCode = 408;
            e2.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.d("Results", "from web: " + rst);

        return responseCode;
    }



@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer headerCode)
{
    progressDialog.dismiss();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("weight", myWeight));
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("height", myHeight));
             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
             HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);       
             String Result = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
     private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            String rLine = "";
            StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            try {
             while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
              answer.append(rLine);
               }
            } 

            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
            return answer;
           }
use it ...
```